# history.push not working for some cases of redirect in React

Tags: reactjs, redirect, use-effect

I'm trying to redirect from the login page to the home page, but the redirect functionality is not working. According to the condition mentioned below, it should go to '/' if no redirect value is provided. But after clicking the sign-in button, it **stays there**.

Also, if I don't enclose the redirect variable inside history.push() with **"{ }"**, the login page loads and
then quickly redirects to '/'

```
import { login } from '../actions/userActions'
import Message from '../components/Message';

const LoginScreen = ({ location, history }) => {

const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
const { loading, userInfo, error } = userLogin;

const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'

useEffect(() => {
    
    if (userInfo) {
        history.push({ redirect })
    }
}, [history, redirect, userInfo])

const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    dispatch(login(email, password))
}

return (
    <FormContainer>
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
        {loading && <Loader />}
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <Form.Group controlId='email'>
                <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type='email' placeholder='Enter Email' value={email} onChange={(e) => 
 setEmail(e.target.value)}></Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId='password'>
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type='password' placeholder='Enter Password' value={password} onChange= 
 {(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}></Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>

            <Button type='submit' variant='primary'>
                Sign In
            </Button>
        </Form>
        <Row className='py-3'>
            <Col>
                New Customer? <Link to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}` : 
 '/register'}>Register</Link>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </FormContainer>
 )
 }  
  export default LoginScreen
```

Comment: Sounds like the `{}` should be removed then if the navigation is occurring as expected. `{ redirect }` isn't going to be a valid object for the `history.push` anyway since it won't have a `pathname` property.

Comment: After removing the braces, if the page is redirecting to '/' , then does that mean location.search is empty?

Comment: That is what `location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'` implies. Does this observed result conflict with expected result? What is the value of `location.search`?

Comment: Got that. I need to trace the value of location.search

Answer (score 0):

The history.push function takes the following keys in its object

> **pathname** - (string) The path of the URL
>
> **search** - (string) The URL query string
>
> **hash** - (string) The URL hash fragment
>
> **state** - (object) location-specific state that was provided to e.g.
> push(path, state) when this location was pushed onto the stack. Only
> available in browser and memory history.

Since redirect is not one of those keys, it doesn't honour it.

However another signature of history function takes the path directly as an argument and so if you call it like below it will work as redirect is your path value

```
history.push(redirect)
```

Comment: After removing the braces, if the page is redirecting to '/' , then does that mean location.search is empty?

Comment: If suppose `?myData=x&appData=y` is location.search then splitting it at `=` will result in `?myData, x&appData, y` and that isn't appropriate. However in your case it seems like location.search is empty. Do you have query params in url when you are on loginScreen

Comment: No, I' m not passing any query string. So the location.search is empty, and the loginoage loads and quickly redirects to '/'

Comment: So what is your expectation?

Comment: the userInfo field is expected to change only after I press the Sign In button, and then the history.push would work. (ideally). But in this case, if(userInfo) is true in the beginning only, hence the page reloads immediately

Comment: you should check what you are receiving from your redux useSelector

Comment: I checked that, in devtools, I'm getting user details, which I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the `{}` should be removed then if the navigation is occurring as expected. `{ redirect }` isn't going to be a valid object for the `history.push` anyway since it won't have a `pathname` property.

If it helps at all, you may also find this [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters) specifically working with the query string useful.

```
const useQuery = () => {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

const LoginScreen = ({ location, history }) => {
  ...

  // Process the query search string and destructure a redirect search
  // value, providing a "/" fallback if there is no redirect search value
  const { redirect = "/" } = useQuery();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      history.push(redirect);
    }
  }, [history, redirect, userInfo]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    ...
  };

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      ...
      <Row className="py-3">
        <Col>
          New Customer?{" "}
          <Link to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}` : "/register"}>
            Register
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};
```